Domain Controller/DNS Server lost ping connection to my Sonicwall Router
I hope you can help me identify what is possibly happening on my network.
I have my ISP modem, then I connect a small 4-port switch (just for test ISP connection in case of internet issues), from here I connect my SonicWall Router/Firewall with DHCP service, then I have a 48-port switch for all my computers and my Domain Controller and DNS server.
I’ve been having disconnections on my computers to the shared files on the server and also lose internet for a few minutes.
Last week, when it happened I pinged from my DC-DNS server to the IP Router/Firewall and I noticed that some packets were lost… then I checked the cable and changed the 48 port switch and the packets in the ping were no longer lost.
Yesterday it happened to me again, I checked the ping from my server to the IP of SonicWall Router/firewall and some packets are lost a some timeouts. (I disconnected the cable from the server and reconnected and no more packets were lost, but I don’t know if this worked or it was just the minutes that passed and it was just a coincidence)
What could be happening?
I see that the DNS configured on the SonicWall Router is my DNS server, but would this be related to losing packets with the ping from the server to the Router? or is this not related to that happening?

DNS doesn't do that – it is not involved in packet delivery... Does the 48-port switch have any port statistics? Are there any other switches connected down from that switch? (Are there any other switches that you don't know about?) I'm mildly suspecting a loop somewhere in your network causing a broadcast storm...

Hello u1686_grawity..  thanks for your time.
I already changed my 48 port Switch for another new one
the old one doesn't have port statistics, but this new one is managed, I will check.
I have other several switches on my network on different areas of the
company, but they are connected to the principal 48port switch.
The first time it happened to me I thought it had been solved by changing the main switch because the server stopped losing packets in the ping.
but for now, it keeps happening randomly. just for a minutes.
